# Delete own Question after it works randomly?

Tags: discussion

I just created [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913108/symfony-2-doctrine-2-search-for-datetime/23914302#23914302) a few minutes ago and searched for help after i couldn't find any solution with my research.

I did nothing else to my code then changing a hardcoded to a variable part again, after both did not work. All mentioned in the Question.

So then after more reseachring i restarted my computer duo to updates and it worked after that. I'm totally suprised about that, but well, it works now.

My Question is just: Should i delete this Question? Or should i just answer it myself like i did and accept the answer as soon as i can? (Must wait 2 days according to the system)

Comment: If you think the answer might be useful to someone else in the future (i.e., they might have the same problem), answer the question. Otherwise, delete.

Comment: That's the point i think needs to be discussed: Is it possible by any chance that somebody will run into the same problem? That the code is fine, also the data and a simple restart will fix whatever went wrong?

Comment: or you can ask _why only after restart?_, But beware, I am not sure if this would be right action to do with this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is a problem that can no longer be reproduced.  We even have a close reason just for these types of questions:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

They generally don't have any lasting value to anyone else.  It's generally a sign that the problem wasn't related to the information in the question, but rather something not mentioned, which means that the question is both not really answerable, nor likely to help anyone else.

You should just delete the question, if you're able to.  Possibly stick a comment on the question explaining what you've said here, if you want.

Comment: Alright, didn't now that, thanks for the information! I'll just delete the Question :)