# deleting own question (related to a bug elsewhere)?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33999359/841108) question and provided a JSFiddle example and pasted some code inside my question.

Unfortunately, this is my first use of JSFiddle, and I forgot to set the JQuery to 2 there. Once I did that, my JSFiddle does not show the bug, and the answer to the question is obvious (and I would not even asked it).

Should I delete [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33999359/841108) mine question?

Related metaquestions: [delete own question after it works randomly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256475/delete-own-question-after-it-works-randomly) [Should I delete my question if suspected it's a bug by the library?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290082/841108)

The point is that I have not identified my bug yet. But the question I have asked is in fact trivial, and I regret having asked it. However, some answers have been upvoted by other people than me...

PS. Perhaps people could be permitted to downvote (not upvote) their own question. If downvoting my question was possible, I might do it.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldn't be able to delete it yourself anyway. You can only delete your own question if it 1) has only one answer (at most) and 2) that answer does not have a positive score. As for if you should _vote_ to delete it... Depends. Do you think it would be useful for future visitors? If so, I'd just leave it for now. If not, then I'd say vote to delete it.

Comment: It probably can be useful... so I am leaving it